# Is it possible to update a Listview on real-time when we use Json?

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I'm a Newbie, so, there are a lot of things that I don't know.

- I'm building my first application, using PHP and Java, and my
  Database is allocated on Phpmyadmin.
- To get the data that I want, I have to create a PHP Query, and output
  everything using Json. To get the Json Data I use Java.
- I have been searching about my question for hours, and unfortunately,
  I couldn't find a specific way to what I want, in my situation. I
  would like to update my ListView automatically when a new record is
  inserted into my Database.
- Lets imagine that you are watching a Listview, and when the owner
  from the application inserts a new record on the table that shows the
  Listview data, automatically the Listview shows a new record.
- My problem is that I am using Json to get the Data, and I can't
  change that. And I would like to find a solution for that.
- So, I would like to know if it is possible or not to do that. I will
  post my full code here:

**Json Tags** - Calling the URL and the Json Tags here:

```
public class ListUsersActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ImageView img;
    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.67/example/db_config.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "pic_url";
    private static final String TAG_USERID = "user_id";
    private static final String TAG_BIRTH_DATE = "birth_date";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
```

**OnCreate** - Calling the Asynctask function, and creating a new arraylist for my Contact list

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lobby);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Calling async task to get json

    new GetContacts().execute();
}
```

**Asynctask** - Getting all the Data json

private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask {

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    // Showing progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListUsersActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Creating service handler class instance
    NewSession app = (NewSession) getApplication();
    String username = app.getUsername();

    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + "?id=" + username, ServiceHandler.GET);

    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

            // Getting JSON Array node
            contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String user_id = c.getString(TAG_USERID);
                String birth_date = c.getString(TAG_BIRTH_DATE);
                String pic_url_get = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                contact.put(TAG_USERID, user_id);
                contact.put(TAG_BIRTH_DATE, getAge(birth_date) + " anos");
                contact.put(TAG_IMAGE, "http://*****/images/" + user_id + "/" + pic_url_get);

                // adding contact to contact list
                contactList.add(contact);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();   
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Calling the adapter**

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */



        costumeadapter adapter =  new costumeadapter(
                        ListUsersActivity.this,
                        contactList,
                        R.layout.list_row,
                        new String[]{ TAG_NAME, TAG_BIRTH_DATE, TAG_USERID},
                        new int[]{ R.id.name,R.id.email, R.id.id });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

**I tried so far**

- To build a Timer and refresh my GetContacts calling class every
  second, but it doesn't work because the user is not able to scroll, and the application crashes
- I tried to use notifyDataSetChanged but I didn't work because I dont know exactly how can i implement that.

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [notifyDataSetChanged example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
adapter.notifydatasetchanged()
```

You have to add it after `setListAdapter()` like:

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Comment: I already tried to implement that, but It didn't change anything. I inserted on onPostExecute, beside setListAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.

> To build a Timer and refresh my GetContacts calling class every
>   second, but it doesn't work because the user is not able to scroll,
>   and the application crashes

Because you're doing it on the main thread. Do it in an `AsyncTask` or a separate thread, that should work.

> I tried to use notifyDataSetChanged but I didn't work because I dont
>   know exactly how can i implement that.

It's simple, you call it in the adapter: `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()` after you update it ([more detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426)).

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how can i build a separate thread?

Comment: That's way too broad to answer here. There are entire books on how to use threads correctly in Java and Android. Check [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).